# How to make a bootable USB drive from backup files of another bootable USB drive?

Tags: drive, pen, bootable

I had a bootable windows 7 pen drive (sandisk 4 GB). Later, I got to use the pen drive for some other purpose, so i copied all the files from pen drive onto my hard disk. Now I want to use those files to make another bootable drive (A kingston 4 GB pen drive). Anybody knows?

Answer (score 0):

Its no issue if you have Win7 or Win8 Operating system install in you can create the boot able pendrive by your own what you have to do is just fallow the simple steps give in the below link.
[Step by step process to create the Bootable pen drive](http://www.techonsolution.com/how-to-create-bootable-pen-drive-in-windows-78-using-command-prompt/)